# Extract or Crop out the cold or hot region of a Thermal Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

For any of the thermal images, there is a difference between hot and cold regions. Is there any python library that crop or extracts these cold or blue regions from the thermal images. These regions can be at anywhere in the image.

Comment: Please give minimal code that produces an example thermal image, to make it easy to help.

Comment: After converting the image into numpy array I have no idea how to extract these cold regions that's why I have asked there. Can you give me any clue so that I can try for it. @kabanus

Comment: you could try otsu thresholding on the non-color-coded image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the hue of each pixel and determine if it is within a threshold to blue and remove it. Here is an example using PIL and colorsys conversions.

```
from PIL import Image
import colorsys

img = Image.open('zebtherm.jpg')

hsv_blue = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(0, 0, 255)
threshold = 0.1

for x in range(img.width):
    for y in range(img.height):
        hsv = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(*img.getpixel((x, y))[0:3])
        if(abs(hsv[0] - hsv_blue[0]) < threshold):
            img.putpixel((x, y), (0, 0, 0))
```

[image: input]
[image: output]

Comment: what would be the threshold if I just want to have blue values and remove others like opposite to what you did ? @Alistair Carscadden

Comment: @ZeeshanNisar You can change the colour you are using as your chromakey. In my example `hsv_blue` is blue and we are removing anything similar to it, you can try changing that to red and the program will remove red pixels instead.